# Git Pycharm change only the local master branch to be exactly like origin master branch

Tags: python, git, pycharm

I have 2 local branches: "master" and "fix".
I also have an origin remote repo with a master branch that is different from my local master branch.

the "fix" branch used to be a copy of the master branch, but then I made a lot of changes:
I changed some of the files, renamed others, added new ones and deleted some.

now, I want my local master branch to be the same as the remote master branch - without changing the "fix" branch!

when I use `git pull` it does not pull all of the files from the remote repository. I am not sure why. 
when I use `git reset --hard origin/master`, it does make the local master the same as the remote one - which is what I wanted - but it also adds files to the "fix" branch!

1. why does this heepens?
2. how can I do this without the "fix" branch changing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to commit your changes to the `fix` branch before switching to the `master` branch

```sh
#current branch: fix
git add .
git status # to verify that every thing is ready to be committed
git commit -m "your commit message"
git checkout master
# current branch: master
git status # to verify if you have commits that weren't yet pushed
git pull # add --rebase option if you have some commits not yet pushed to avoid adding merge commit
```

I hope it helps :)